# Meteor: Need simple approach for admin CRM

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to come up with a way to secure a set of Admin CRM pages that control a Meteor application I'm working on. There's just one codebase, with the server, customer facing website and admin facing website in one project.

I need a login page which can verify one username and password pair, and a simple way to check the status of the user on both the client and server side. I also need a way of the admin's authorization timing out if it hasn't been used for x minutes.

I've looked at the meteor accounts package and it's just way too much fluff for what I need. This website will only ever have one admin user, so there will only be one set of admin username and password to store. I don't want it stored in the database, rather loaded with a settings file on the server on application start. It doesn't need roles, emails, password reset functionality.

Any recommendations for a package or approach I could use to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said that the accounts:password package seemed a little "overkill", but in reality it really isn't.  What you are gaining there is pluggable UI (via accounts-ui and other packages that build off it).  The approach I have taken is this (which happens to work well even for apps that do support multiple users, since ultimately you still need to bootstrap your start users).

First, I use a combination of accounts:password and alanning:roles.  If you absolutely don't need the roles portion, you could probably get away without it, but in all my personal cases I have found it useful to have multiple levels of ACLs for the various users.  We could get into a whole philosophical discussion on using roles/groups to lock down individual features, but that's sort of off topic for this discussion.

Next you need to boot-strap the user(s).  Somewhere in your `/server` folder you will do something like:

```
if (Meteor.users.find({}).count() == 0) {
  // No users created...create default users
  Accounts.createUser({
    username: 'myuser',
    email: 'myuser@mydomain.com',
    password: 'myp4ssw0rd!',
    profile: { profileProp: 'propVal` }
  });
  // Add new user to whatever roles needed
}
```

There are some more things I usually do here, like checking to see if my roles exist, and if not, create them before I try to handle the users, but the key here is to do that when the server starts up.

Once you have your user(s) and role(s) created, it's a matter of checking/verifying the user/roles in your app.  For menu items you can show/hide stuff based on whether the user is logged in and/or has a certain role, and you should also verify in your application routes that require ACLs, like your admin route.  In addition, use the user id in all your publications as well to limit the data your users can see.  Don't rely solely on hiding a menu option...security through obscurity just doesn't work.

Why do I suggest doing it this way?  First off, it's really not THAT much code.  You could literally do this in probably 20 lines, max, and have a full authentication setup.  And the benefit of those lines of code greatly outweigh the 30min tops it would take you, as you will now have "real" user authentication in your app and have the ability to do things like OAuth if you ever decide to in the future.  Most importantly, you unlock pre-build UI plugins that you don't have to code, built-in and add-on methods to help check ACLs, the ability to lock down data by user, and you don't have to try to implement your own solution.